# SNMP query to get UPS information

Tags: c, winapi, snmp, net-snmp

I'm trying to get the information from an apc ups from winapi but my code is failing **SnmpMgrRequest**  and when checked the error code it is giving it as 40 which is not mentioned in the SNMP ERROR code list for winapi. I have posted the code below .
Any help in fixing this would be great .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WINSNMP.H>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Strsafe.h>
#include <WinNT.h>
#include <Mgmtapi.h>
#include <Snmp.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "WSNMP32.LIB")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mgmtapi.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Snmpapi.lib")    

int main()
{
    int choice;
    LPSNMP_MGR_SESSION MgrSession;     
    INT nRetries = 1;
    AsnObjectIdentifier oid;
    RFC1157VarBindList variableBindings;
    AsnInteger errorStatus = 0;
    AsnInteger errorIndex = 0;
    char lpAgentAddress[50] ;

    LPSTR lpAgentCommunity ="public";
    variableBindings.list = NULL;
    variableBindings.len = 0;
    SNMPAPI MgrStatus;

    printf("\n SNMP Program \n ");
    printf("\n What You want to know ? \n ");
    printf("1---UPS Type \n");
    printf("2---Battery capacity \n");
    printf("3---Battery Temperature \n ");
    printf("4---Battery runtime remain \n ");
    printf("Enter your choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("\n Enter the ip address : ");
    scanf_s(" %s",lpAgentAddress);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 :
            variableBindings.len++;
            SnmpMgrStrToOid(".1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.1.1.1.1.0", &oid); // oid for apc ups 
            variableBindings.list = (SnmpVarBind *)SNMP_realloc(variableBindings.list, sizeof(SnmpVarBind) *variableBindings.len);
            SnmpUtilOidCpy(&variableBindings.list[0].name,&oid);
            variableBindings.list->value.asnType = ASN_NULL;
            MgrSession = SnmpMgrOpen((LPSTR)lpAgentAddress,lpAgentCommunity,1500,2);
            if (MgrSession == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n Session has failed ");
                SnmpUtilVarBindListFree(&variableBindings);
                return false;
            }
            MgrStatus = SnmpMgrRequest(MgrSession,SNMP_PDU_GET,&variableBindings,&errorStatus,&errorIndex);
            if (MgrStatus == NULL)
            {
                printf("\n Could not query the device ");
                printf("\n Error1 = %d",GetLastError());

                SnmpUtilVarBindListFree(&variableBindings);
                return false;
            } 
            else
            {
                if (errorStatus > 0){
                    printf("Error Returned from the agent ");

                    SnmpUtilVarBindListFree(&variableBindings);
                    return false;
                } 
                else
                {
                    for(unsigned int i=0;i<variableBindings.len;i++)
                    {
                        int infolen;
                        char systeminfo[2048];
                        char *snmpstring;
                        infolen = variableBindings.list[i].value.asnValue.string.length;
                        snmpstring =(char *) variableBindings.list[i].value.asnValue.string.stream;

                        memcpy(systeminfo, snmpstring,infolen);  //get the system information and copy in the array systeminfo 
                        systeminfo[infolen] = '\0'; 
                        printf("%s",systeminfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the mib of UPS for OID, can you get if via net-snmp ?

Comment: @girijesh Chauhan : is it mib version you are talking about

Comment: The libraries you are using I don't use. If you code compiled. Check OID again. also try to fir query using net-snmp first.

Comment: hello girijesh i'm able to get the data from netsnmp but as pointed by remy i'm getting an timeout error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error code it is giving it as 40 which is not mentioned in the SNMP ERROR code list for winapi

If [`SnmpMgrRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is returning 0 and `GetLastError()` is returning 40, then that is `SNMP_MGMTAPI_TIMEOUT`, which is defined in Mgmtapi.h:

```
#define SNMP_MGMTAPI_TIMEOUT                40
```

`SNMP_MGMTAPI_TIMEOUT` **is documented** as a possible error code from [`SnmpMgrRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError, which may return one of the following error codes.
>
> SNMP_MGMTAPI_TIMEOUT
>   The request timed-out.